# Core data for iOS 8.0 app using XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm experiencing some difficulties in getting my app to use core data to store information which is book marked by the user.
It currently saves this information to an xml file (without core data) and I'm not sure how to transition this to use core data.

So far i have this in my AppDelegate.m

```
    // Create Managed Object
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Album" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[[self managedObjectContext] save:nil];
```

i am then trying to use the entity i have created which is called 'Album' and the attributes within the entity which are 'albumName' and 'albumArtist' both 'strings'

This is the code in the TableViewController.m

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        if (searching) {
    // use for interaction with search list
    NSDictionary *tune = [searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //check label for system messages
    if ([[tune valueForKey:@"mbid"] intValue] != -1) {
        //Add the new album to your list
        [albums addObject:tune];

        // clear the search text
        [searchBar setText:@""];

        //Remove the cancel/done button from navigation bar
        [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];

        //clear the search results and reset state
        searching = NO;
        [searchResults removeAllObjects];

    //trying to use core data here to store the row selected by the user 

        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        // step 1 - Create new NSManagedObject for your CoreData model

        // step 2 - Set values for its attributes
        [newAlbum setValue:name.varchar forKey:@"name"];
        [newAlbum setValue:artist.varchar forKey:@"artist"];

        // step 3 - Save NSManagedContext

        // step 4 - Update your list of object in 'albums' for the table view.

        //force the table to reload and redraw
        [[self tableView] reloadData];

        /*
        //Sort albums
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        [albums sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]];

        // this was the original method for Storing data

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *yourArrayFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"albums.xml"];
        [albums writeToFile:yourArrayFileName atomically:YES];
         */

    }
} else {
    // use for interaction with album list

    NSDictionary *tune = [albums objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    FilmDetailViewController *vc = [[FilmDetailViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:@"FilmDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [vc setTune:tune];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; //slides the view in from the right

}
    }
```

I have tried to outline the steps i would need to take but not sure where to start. any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: You are missing the basics of how to use Core Data.  This is not a tutorial site, though mini tutorials can result from a SO question.  First, go read the documentation on how to use Core Data.  Apple has really good documentation on this, and you can find most of it by using help in Xcode.  There are also some really good books and tutorials available.  Google should provide you with more than you could ask for.  Finally, once you studied the basics, please come back with any specific questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of good tutorials on the web. Here is a really good step by step tutorial to get into using core data. (http://code.tutsplus.com/series/core-data-from-scratch--cms-653)

Also check out some YouTube videos. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgNq5-go-ws)